# Move current changes to a new branch without initial commit

Tags: git

I did some (uncommited) changes on a new feature on my project and I noticed that the work on it will be more than I thought. So I decided to move these changes to a new branch. If I create a new branch with

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

the changes are shown in both branches, the master branch and my new branch. To hide the changes in the master branch, is it the only way to commit the (incomplete) changes in my new branch? I would like to avoid any commits with incomplete changes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can commit in the `branch_name` your work in progress.

Then, when you are ready to complete that work (in `branch_name`), you will **amend** your commit.

```
git commit --amend
```

See [`git commit` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> `--amend`: Replace the tip of the current branch by creating a new commit.

You will then push that amended commit to your upstream repo.

In the meantime, you can go back to `master` without any issue (and without seeing those changes isolated in `branch_name`).